# How can I use mysqli / php to update all records after a query has already been executed?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a user form that sets a single record "current". No more than one record can be set to current at a time. So, I present the user a single drop down list, they choose the item they want to set current and hit "UPDATE" at the bottom of the form.

The PHP/Mysqli needs to go in and set all records column "current" to a value of 0 then update the one from the form to a value of "1".

Initially, I just did a simple count the number of rows, and run a bunch of queries to update the column to 0 or 1 if the loop counter = the id of the row. Well... that broke quick as I started doing testing on other portions and the index numbers got higher than the total number of rows. Yes, dumb way to do it initially!

Here's what I tried to do with the PHP / MySQL code:

```html
// $link  is the database link defined elsewhere. This does work as I use it all over the place
$setCurrent = X; // This is the number passed from my form

$init_query = "SELECT id, current FROM myTable";

if ($stmt = $link->$prepare($init_query) {
  $stmt->execute() or die ($stmt->error);
  $stmt ->bind_result($id, $current)
  while ($stmt->fetch()){   
    if ($id == $setCurrent){
    
    $update_sql = "UPDATE myTable SET current ='1' WHERE id='".$setCurrent."'";
    $stmt2 = $link->prepare($update_sql);
    $stmt2->execute; 
    
    }
    
    else {
    $update_sql =  "UPDATE myTable SET current ='0' WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $stmt2 = $link->prepare($update_sql);
    $stmt2->execute;
 }
 $stmt->close();
```

This fails and gives me a Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute on boolean in .....

I am racking my brain over this and can't figure out what the heck is going on. Its been a few years since I have worked in PHP/MySql and this is my first forray into OO Mysqli. Please be gentle :)

Comment: could be handy to mention the line where your script fails. Which query gives the error?

Comment: it's probably the extra $ in prepare() ?

Comment: I transposed the code from a different system. The syntax works on the development system. The extra $ and the curleys are just fat fingering.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two closing curly braces. One for the first `if()` and the other for `while()`

Answer (score 1):

why do them one at a time? You can do it in one query

```
$setCurrent = X; 
$query = 'UPDATE myTable
          SET `current` = (id = :current)';
$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':current', $setCurrent);
$stmt->execute();
```

(and misusing the fact that if id equals $setCurrent,  the part between ( )  resolves to true, which is 1.)

some explaining:

`SELECT 10=10;` would give a kind of "TRUE". But as Mysql does not give true, it give 1.
the same goes for:

`SELECT 10=20;`  This is FALSE, so gives you 0.

Now back to your query: you want to get a value 0 for all record for which id not equal to some-number. And you want 1 when equal:
So you have to compare the column id's value to $setCurrent. When they match you get 1 and you put that 1 into the column "current"
And when they don't match, all other cases, then you get a 0 and that 0 goes into the column Current.

And yes, this could also be done as:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET `current` = CASE id
                 WHEN $setCurrent  THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END CASE
```

or using IF,
But they other syntax is way shorter

**edit**
backtics are needed around column name, as current is a reserved word

Comment: Can you provide more context for  '(and misusing the fact that if id equals $setCurrent, the part between ( ) resolves to true, which is 1.)"

Comment: My table is set up such that

id, name, date, current

The form provides a drop down so that the user can find "name" and say, yup thats what I want current. Go!

The form handler take the id associated with that name and passes it to the overall function, setting the row associated with that id 's 'current' column to the value 1 and then all other rows current column to "0".

Comment: @user3723090 I added some explanation above

Comment: I appreciate the straight forwardness of the response. I'll give it a whirl and report back.

Comment: Well.. results are in. That didn't work. I blame my lack of full understanding of the OO way to do this properly to why I can't figure it out. The code seems be be having an issue with the bindValue() portion and its throwing a "Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in <my file name: line> Stack trace: #0"

Comment: current is a reserved word in Mysql. So it cannot be used as a column name. That is, unless you place it between backtics

Comment: I managed to get it to work fine using the CASE above. The one change I made was the last CASE, that wasn't needed. Ill continue to fart around with the other version because I'm not one to give up.